# Linux SMB to \\domainname ends up "tree connect failed: NT_STATUS_DUPLICATE_NAME "

Tags: linux, samba, centos7, server-message-block, dfs

**Issue:**

From CentOS7 machine:

```
smbclient -L %domainname%.com --user=%username%
```

Result:

```
tree connect failed: NT_STATUS_DUPLICATE_NAME
```

This is especially when I try to connect to `//domainname.com`, which would end up being like `//domainname.com/sysvol` or `//domainname.com/netlogon`.

Overall the end goal is to connect to a DFS share that lives off the domainname.

**Attemps and results:**

`smbclient -L %Aservername% --user=%username%` = Works fine

`smbclient -L %IPaddress(of any server or DC)% --user=%username%` = Works fine

`smbclient -L %domainname% --user=%username%` = DuplicateName prompt

I've tried adding a `CNAME` in Windows DNS like `%TestName%` to `%domainname%`, but it still comes up with duplicate name.

In CentOS `/etc/hosts` I've mapped `%domainname%` to `%testname%`, but it still comes up with duplicate name.

In CentOS `/etc/hosts` I've mapped IP of DC1 to `%testname%`

In CentOS `/etc/hosts` I've mapped IP of DC2 to `%testname%`

In CentOS `/etc/hosts` I've mapped IP of DC3 to `%testname%`, but it still comes up with duplicate name.

* Firewall has been turned off for this testing.

Any help would be appreciated. I've spent many hours now trying to sort this out.

Comment: http://serverfault.com/questions/17946/connecting-with-samba-to-a-windows-share-returns-nt-status-duplicate-name

Comment: http://serverfault.com/questions/17946/connecting-with-samba-to-a-windows-share-returns-nt-status-duplicate-name

Answer (score 0):

As a workaround, you can use your domain controller's name instead of domain name. The downside is, you won't be able to access the share while this domain controller is down. But it should rarely happen anyway.

Answer (score 0):

According to my notes for a CentOS 7 system trying to access DFS shares, you need to include these lines (at the bottom is fine) in `/etc/request-key.conf`. They are not in the default.

```
create  cifs.spnego     *       *               /usr/sbin/cifs.upcall -c %k
create  dns_resolver    *       *               /usr/sbin/cifs.upcall %k
```

That was for a regular mount command, but maybe it applies here. The file referred to comes from base package cifs-utils.

My notes point to this site: http://mikemstech.blogspot.com/2012/10/how-to-mount-dfs-share-in-linux.html